# How to handle an error while decoding a Base64 string

Tags: c, base64, standards

I am trying to write a small Base64 coder/decoder program, and I'm trying to figure out if there are any rules, or any guidelines, or expected behavior, when a run into a character that is not valid.

I could fail fast (complain and exit), ignore non-valid characters (like I would do for newlines, etc.), or do a junk-in, junk-out approach (where the data will be partially decoded, and the rest depends on the severity or the exact number of errors).

On a similar point: I imagine I should ignore newlines (like in PEM files, where lines are broken at a 64-character length), but are there any other control characters that I could expect, and should ignore properly?

If it is of any interest, I'm coding in pure (vanilla) C, which doesn't already have the library for it.  But that detail shouldn't really matter for the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is over-broad. There are at least a dozen variants of base64 encoding in use. Choose the variant you want to use, and use the rules and restrictions of that variant.

Comment: I am primarily basing my implementation on the description in the RFC's on HTTP (1945, 2068), which is based on the MIME RFC's (as far back as 1341).  However, none of those sources seemed to describe what to do in case of errors.

Comment: Well, yeah, I would expect RFC1945 and RFC2068 to be very vague when it comes to content encoding, since they define the HTTP protocol. You might look at RFC2045 for MIME base64. However, error handling will completely depend on the needs of your particular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies. The RFC's on MIME ([1341](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1341#page-18), [1521](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1521#page-22), [2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-25)) contain the following paragraph, which I could not find until now:

> The output stream (encoded bytes)  must  be  represented  in lines of no more than 76 characters each. **All line breaks or other characters not found in Table 1 must be ignored  by decoding  software.** In  base64 data, characters other than those in  Table  1,  line  breaks,  and  other  white  space probably  indicate  a  transmission  error,  about  which  a warning  message  or  even  a  message  rejection  might  be appropriate under some circumstances.

In any case, it is appropriate that this question and answer be available ono StackOverflow.

P.S. If there are other standards of Base64 with other guidelines, links and quotes are appropriate in other answers.